# Remove excess <br> tags before table

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am designing a page with WordPress. When I use `<table>` in my page it, creates an excess of `<br>` tags before the table.

I did check the code but it does not have any `<br>` tags. If i check it in Firebug 5, `<br>` tags are generated automatically.

Note: I used izcalender plugin when I remove it my code works normally.

What is reason for this problem?

Comment: Would be useful if you posted the code where you are trying to add a table to WP. Try disabling all of your plugins that are active and running your code again. If it works you know it is another plugin, not your code. Slowly turn on plugins and continue testing until you know it is definitely izcalender. Otherwise, it's hard to suggest how to fix your code without seeing it. Thanks.

Comment: @SandhanaMurali i am facing the same problem too.Trying to figure it out. But it is quite complex to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referred a link regarding this problem.
I hope that this will help you.
But make sure you read this entire article.

[Excess of break  tags](http://blogs.voxeo.com/behindtheblog/2008/08/13/getting-rid-of-extra-br-lines-in-wordpress-mu/)

I am referring for some other problems. this will help you to solve yours.

Comment: This link is not dead, but it is useless. The domain ownership looks to have been changed and a redirect put in.

Answer (score 1):

1) There could be something like $before_widget; $after_widget; which gives 
 izcalender plugin remove or comment those

if not

2) Add in Your CSS like {margin-top:-20px}

I think this will work